# SSIS: How to find the parent of a given package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS Project with about 100 packages, and it's difficult to find the execution order of it all. I don´t even know which one is the master package. That being said, my question is: Given a package, is there a way to determine where that particular package is being called? Or in other words, what is the precedence of that package?

Comment: What do you mean here? Packages in SSIS don't have a hierarchy structure; they all belong to a project. They don't have a "parent". I'm assuming that you mean that some packages aren't directly called and are called via the SSIS Package Task from another? Have you consulted your company's documentation on the packages? That *should* tell you what package is called by what (and what they do). If not, there's no easy way to find out. Either you'll need to open your packages and inspect any SSIS Package tasks, or otherwise you could inspect the XML.

Comment: What version of SSIS are you working with? If 2012+, are they using the Project Deployment Model (SSISDB)?

Comment: The most common route for running a child package will be the existence of an `Execute Package Task` but you could be looking for an `Execute SQL Task` as they might want to run a package in asynchronous mode. They might also launch the child package using .NET so a `Script Task` would need to be inspected. The next challenge in finding order is how the orchestrator package determines said order. If you're lucky, it's serial execution (Execute Package Task 1 -> EPT 2 -> ... EPT x) My pattern looks at a table to determine package dependency and then uses Foreach Loop Container to run packages

Comment: @Larnu , Parent-child is a name of a design pattern that consists of packages executing other packages. One package can execute another package through the use of one of the following:*The Execute Package Task,
*T-SQL commands,
The Execute Process Task (using the dtexec.exe utility). Source [link] (https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2014/02/07/parent-child-ssis-architecture/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, use `Edit >> Find and Replace >> Find` in `Files`.

**Find what:** Name of Package

**Look In:** Entire Solution

**Find Options:** Look at these file types: *.dtsx

Will return a list of packages that reference the target package.
Not ideal, but a quick and dirty way to get a list of all possible parents.

The child reference will appear as `"<PackageName>ChildPackage.dtsx</PackageName>"`.